# Opening an already-open file with GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

Suppose that the file A.txt is already opened with GNU-emacs, but I don't notice it, so I try opening it (again) with

```
emacs A.txt
```

Instead of just showing the already-open window it opens a second one!

(This is of course annoying, since I will end up with 2 conflicting versions.)

How can I avoid this (under ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 4):

Command `emacs` starts a new instance of the application.

What you are looking for is [`emacsclient`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html) which connects to an existing `emacs` instance and tells it to edit the file.

You need to [start the server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) first though.

Comment: I started the server using 

  "emacs --daemon"

and then I did twice

  "emacsclient -c A.txt &"

but it did open a second window.

Am I missing something?